# Can I label a list in Trello?

Tags: trello

I want to assign labels to various lists in one Trello board. For example, my trello board is one project; the lists inside the board represent various initiatives for the larger project; each of the initiatives relates to a particular strategic activity (use. share, build). So I'd like to label each list according to its strategic activity, but it seems only cards can be labeled.

Answer (score 5):

That is correct; only cards can be labeled.  You're not missing anything.  Nor can you (currently) automatically assign colors to newly created cards in a given list, although you could always write something that took advantage of [the Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/) to do what you want, if that makes sense for you.

Comment: Automatically assigning labels to a card according to their list is now possible using the Butler Power-Up. (https://trello.com/power-ups/5935cab6b26816f9d49fd814/butler)