# How do I title/label lists?

Tags: trello, trello-lists

I am new to Trello and not too technology-savvy.

How can I change the label or title of my lists?

The three default lists are To Do/Doing/Done, but I would prefer to use the board in a different way, using each list to organize a different component of the overall project. There was [Can I label a list in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31944/can-i-label-a-list-in-trello) and the answer was that lists cannot be re-labelled.

However, on the Trello Development board the lists are labelled Ideas/Known Issues/Next up, etc. I saw another user's screenshot where her lists were labelled Idea Pipeline and Planning.

So it seems like it must be possible.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

Only `Cards` can be `labelled`, labelling in Trello means the Card is assigned to a category (represented by a coloured "tab" at the top of the `Card`).

Lists can however be renamed (their `title` changed) by simply clicking on the `title`, which puts it into Edit mode.
When you create a new list (using `Options -> More -> Add List` from the right-hand-side menu bar) you can specify it's `title`.

Answer (score 1):

To rename a `Card`, you can double click the name of the card in the `Board` and the card name would become editable.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the title of a list to change it.